# Combing split dataframes horizontally

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which is nearly 10k rows long. I have split this every x rows based on where it needs to be split using:

```
split(data_filt, (0:nrow(data_filt) %/% 561))
```

This returns...15 of this output below.

```
$`14`
# A tibble: 561 x 6
   name1  name2 name3    name4 name5 value
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 events data  attacker pos   y1    NA   
 2 events data  attacker pos   y2    NA   
 3 events data  attacker pos   y3    NA   
 4 events data  attacker pos   y4    NA   
 5 events data  attacker pos   y5    NA   
 6 events data  attacker pos   y6    NA   
 7 events data  attacker pos   y7    NA   
 8 events data  attacker pos   y8    NA   
 9 events data  attacker pos   y9    NA   
10 events data  attacker pos   y10   258  
# ... with 551 more rows

$`15`
# A tibble: 561 x 6
   name1  name2 name3    name4 name5 value
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 events data  attacker pos   x1    NA   
 2 events data  attacker pos   x2    NA   
 3 events data  attacker pos   x3    NA   
 4 events data  attacker pos   x4    NA   
 5 events data  attacker pos   x5    NA   
 6 events data  attacker pos   x6    NA   
 7 events data  attacker pos   x7    NA   
 8 events data  attacker pos   x8    NA   
 9 events data  attacker pos   x9    NA   
10 events data  attacker pos   x10   630
```

I'm looking the easiest method to combine these together horizontally in a cbind type approach please (or if it is actually easier to name them uniquely when each is created/split from the main dataframe that works too, I can use cbind on it all then).

Thanks

Comment: It's possible you do not need to split and then cbind, but rather want a `pivot_wider()` type solution. It is hard to tell based on the example.

Comment: `do.call(cbind, split(data_filt, (0:nrow(data_filt) %/% 561)))`

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Few things:

1. R uses 1-based arrays, so you are probably seeing the following warning:

   ```
   # Warning in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) :
   #   data length is not a multiple of split variable
   ```

   That's relevant, don't ignore it, don't exclude it in questions.

   Also, if you are doing this programmatically, it's generally better to use `seq_len(nrow(.))` instead of `1:nrow(.)`, since the latter will behave incorrectly if you ever (accidentally) pass it a 0-row frame.
2. We can use `do.call(cbind, ...)` to combine them, but it will complain if/when the last element has fewer rows. We'll need to guard against that by appending `NA`-rows.
3. Column names will be an issue, we can adjust it with `make.unique`.

```r
mt <- mtcars[1:13,1:3]
mt_spl <- split(mt, (seq_len(nrow(mt))-1) %/% 5)
mt_spl
# $`0`
#                    mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360
# $`1`
#             mpg cyl disp
# Valiant    18.1   6  225
# Duster 360 14.3   8  360
# Merc 240D  24.4   4  147
# Merc 230   22.8   4  141
# Merc 280   19.2   6  168
# $`2`
#             mpg cyl disp
# Merc 280C  17.8   6  168
# Merc 450SE 16.4   8  276
# Merc 450SL 17.3   8  276
```

Next step is to make sure they all have the same number of rows.

```r
mt_spl <- lapply(mt_spl, function(x) rbind(x, x[NA,][rep(1, maxrows-nrow(x)),]))
mt_spl
# $`0`
#                    mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360
# $`1`
#             mpg cyl disp
# Valiant    18.1   6  225
# Duster 360 14.3   8  360
# Merc 240D  24.4   4  147
# Merc 230   22.8   4  141
# Merc 280   19.2   6  168
# $`2`
#             mpg cyl disp
# Merc 280C  17.8   6  168
# Merc 450SE 16.4   8  276
# Merc 450SL 17.3   8  276
# NA           NA  NA   NA
# NA.1         NA  NA   NA
```

(The intermediate use of `x[NA,]` ensures that we are `rbind`ing the appropriate version of `NA` in each column; while R usually binds just find and figures out which to use, I like to be explicit. BTW, did you know there are at least seven kinds of `NA`?)

From here, we can combine them.

```r
do.call(cbind, unname(mt_spl))
#                    mpg cyl disp  mpg cyl disp  mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 18.1   6  225 17.8   6  168
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 14.3   8  360 16.4   8  276
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108 24.4   4  147 17.3   8  276
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 22.8   4  141   NA  NA   NA
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 19.2   6  168   NA  NA   NA
```

If you need the names to be unique (so you can reference specific columns by-name), then remove the `unname`:

```r
do.call(cbind, mt_spl)
#                   0.mpg 0.cyl 0.disp 1.mpg 1.cyl 1.disp 2.mpg 2.cyl 2.disp
# Mazda RX4          21.0     6    160  18.1     6    225  17.8     6    168
# Mazda RX4 Wag      21.0     6    160  14.3     8    360  16.4     8    276
# Datsun 710         22.8     4    108  24.4     4    147  17.3     8    276
# Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6    258  22.8     4    141    NA    NA     NA
# Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8    360  19.2     6    168    NA    NA     NA
```

This does it this way because it prepends the name of each of the `mt_spl` names (`"0", "1", "2"`) to the column names. Technically, these are not normal R column names (starting with a number is discouraged and difficult to do accidentally), so we can change that with

```r
do.call(data.frame, mt_spl)
#                   X0.mpg X0.cyl X0.disp X1.mpg X1.cyl X1.disp X2.mpg X2.cyl X2.disp
# Mazda RX4           21.0      6     160   18.1      6     225   17.8      6     168
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0      6     160   14.3      8     360   16.4      8     276
# Datsun 710          22.8      4     108   24.4      4     147   17.3      8     276
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4      6     258   22.8      4     141     NA     NA      NA
# Hornet Sportabout   18.7      8     360   19.2      6     168     NA     NA      NA
```